# How to make a background image of one section to show little over second section?

Tags: css

Here is my PSD [image]

I want to make this image exacly to go little below to second section. Here is my HTML look that i have made till now.
[image]

Its not going below as i dont know what will be its css. I think i have to change css of hero background class.. may be overflow or something else. Any one can help me to resolve my problem ? BY the way this hero image is seperate image.. let me show you the picture.[image]

Below is the html code of the first and second section.

```
   <div class="hero-background">
        <!-- Navigation bar -->
      <div class="navbar-fixed">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <nav>
              <div class="container">
              <a href="#" class="brand-logo hide-on-small-only">
                <img class="resonsive-img" src="img/logo.png"/>
              </a>
                        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons black-text">menu</i></a>
              <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#howItWorks">How it works</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#aboutUs">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
                <li><a class="white-text" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn stack-btn" href="#stack">Earn more</a></li>
              </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            </div>
      </div>

        <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo sidenav-close">
                <img class="resonsive-img" src="img/logo.png"/>
            </a>
            <li><a class="mobile-menu-text sidenav-close" href="#howItWorks">How it works</a></li>
            <li><a class="mobile-menu-text sidenav-close" href="#aboutUs">About</a></li>
            <li><a class="mobile-menu-text sidenav-close" href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a class="mobile-menu-text sidenav-close" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn stack-btn sidenav-close" href="#stack">Earn more</a></li>
        </ul>

      <!-- End Navigation bar -->

    <!-- Hero section -->
      <section id="hero">
                <!-- Desktop & tablet version -->
          <div class="row valign-wrapper hide-on-small-only" style="padding-top: 10%; height: 100vh;">
            <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h2 class="hero-title1">Earn more effortlessly</h2>
                            <h5 class="hero-title5">Stack boosts your wealth by automatically investing your excess cash</h5>
                            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn stack-btn" href="#howItWorks">Show me how</a>
                        </div>

            </div>
            <div class="right" style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 5%">
              <img class="resonsive-img" src="img/macbook.png"/>
            </div>
          </div>
                <!-- Mobile version -->
                <div class="col s12 hide-on-med-and-up" style="padding-top: 30%">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h2 class="hero-title1">Earn more effortlessly</h2>
                        <p class="hero-title5"><b>Stack boosts your wealth by automatically investing your excess cash</b></p>
                        <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn stack-btn" href="#howItWorks">Show me how</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </section>
    </div>

    <!-- End Hero section -->
<!-- How It Works section -->
<section id="howItWorks">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-heading">
      <h2 class="center-align">How It Works</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col l6 m12 center-align">
        <row>
           <i class="large material-icons howItWorks-icon">device_hub</i>
        </row>
        <row>
          <div class="howItWorks">
            <h5>Seamless Connection</h5>
            <p>Grow your Stack by connecting your bank account and creating your investment profile in just two minutes.</p>
          </div>
        </row>
      </div>
      <div class="col l6 m12 center-align">
        <row>
          <i class="large material-icons howItWorks-icon">trending_up</i>
        </row>
        <row>
          <div class="howItWorks">
            <h5>Boosted Earnings</h5>
            <p>A smart algorithm monitors your spending patterns. Any spare cash is transferred into your Stack investment portfolio, giving you higher returns.</p>
          </div>
        </row>
      </div>
      <div class="col l6 m12 center-align">
        <row>
          <i class="large material-icons howItWorks-icon">cached</i>
        </row>
        <row>
          <div class="howItWorks">
            <h5>Frictionless Withdrawals</h5>
            <p>We know that sometimes life gives you lemons, so Stack lets you access your cash in real time with our instant bank withdrawal feature.</p>
          </div>
        </row>
      </div>
      <div class="col l6 m12 center-align">
        <row>
          <i class="large material-icons howItWorks-icon">account_balance</i>
        </row>
        <row>
          <div class="howItWorks">
            <h5>Strong Foundations</h5>
            <p>You can trust Stack's tech - its origins are in advanced computer science, nobel prize winning economics and is fully licensed and governed by ASIC*.</p>
            <small>* Australian Securities Investment Commission</small>
          </div>
        </row>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End How It Works section -->

<!-- Stack section -->

<section>
  <div class="stack-heading-background">
    <div class="container center-align">
      <div class="section-heading">
        <h2>Stack earns you more</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="stack">
  <div class="stack-background">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="col s12">
        <!-- {% csrf_token %} -->
        <row class="center-align">
          <div class="col s12 stack-heading5">
            <h5>How much do you save per month?</h5>
          </div>
          <div style="padding-top: 50px;">
            <div id="savings-slider"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="center-align">
            <h5 id="input-format"></h5>
          </div>
        </row>
        <row>
          <div class="center-align">
                        <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                        <span class="answer">The average millenial saves $500 per month. Millenials are actually the best savers in Australia! Must be all those Netflix and chill nights...</span></p>
          </div>
        </row>
        <row class="center-align">
          <div class="col s12 stack-heading5" style="padding-top:10px">
            <h5>What are you saving for?</h5>
          </div>
        </row>
                <row>
                    <div class="col m6">
                        <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="savingTargetHoliday" name="inputSavingTarget" value="5000"/>
                  <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/holiday.png">
                  <div class="stack-label">Holiday</div>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="savingTargetCar" name="inputSavingTarget" value="25000"/>
                  <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/car.png">
                  <div class="stack-label">Car</div>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="savingTargetHouse" name="inputSavingTarget" value="75000"/>
                  <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/house.png">
                  <div class="stack-label">House</div>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="savingTargetWedding" name="inputSavingTarget" value="20000"/>
                  <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/wedding.png">
                  <div class="stack-label">Wedding</div>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" id="savingTargetRetirement" name="inputSavingTarget" value="1000000"/>
                  <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/retirement.png">
                  <div class="stack-label">Retirement</div>
                </label>
              </div>
                    </div>
          <div class="stack-radio-btn center-align">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" id="savingTargetAvocado" name="inputSavingTarget" value="2500"/>
              <img class="circle responsive-img hoverable" src="img/icon/avocado.png">
              <div class="stack-label">Smashed Avo</div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </row>
                <row>
                    <div class="holidayAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">Cocktails on the beach anyone?! $5,000 should do it in style</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">Vroom vroom! Impress your peeps with a brand new $20,000 car</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="houseAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">Not everyone is locked out of the housing market! $75,000 should get you a deposit on a sweet pad</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="weddingAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">Splurge $20,000 on your big day and don’t feel guilty about skimping out on your distant relatives!</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="retirementAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">You'll need at least $1,000,000 to enjoy the perks of retirement...like making a grand entrance at the pokies in the latest model mobility scooter!</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="avocadoAnswer center-align">
                            <p><i class="small material-icons howItWorks-icon">info</i>
                            <span class="answer">Two raw vegan brunches every weekend will set you back $2,500 each year! Better start saving...</span></p>
                    </div>
                </row>
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:15%">
          <div class="input-field col s12 center-align">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light stack-btn" type="submit" name="action">Submit
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- End Stack section -->
```

Now it my css code

```
/*------------------------------------*\
    #HERO Section
\*------------------------------------*/

.hero-background {
  background-image: url("../img/hero-bg.png");
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right top;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 993px) {
  .hero-background {
    background-position: 75% 50%;
  }
}

.hero-title1 {
  color: #4741d6;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.hero-title5 {
  color: #4741d6;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

/*------------------------------------*\
    #HOW IT WORKS Section
\*------------------------------------*/

.howItWorks {
  padding: 0px 60px 20px 60px;
}

.howItWorks-icon {
  color: #4741d6;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:visible`?

Comment: Yes tried overflow:visible to .hero-background class.. but nothing happen

Comment: Ah. Just seen. You have it as `background`. That does — not — work. You want to set it as `<img>`.

Comment: Could you upload the pictures online and use the links on your code? This question is about the pictures, so it would be helpful to see them.

Comment: Here is the link to code http://djgt.co.uk/random/stack/

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the link that you provided and i tried to achieve the same

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/s92o1xq9/1/

you have to use **media query** for different **breakpoints** to change the **ratio** of the **img**

```css
.hero-background {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 75vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.overlay img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.data {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-background">
  <div class="overlay">
    <img src="http://djgt.co.uk/random/stack/img/hero-bg.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="data">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione atque, error maiores minima modi ipsam possimus rerum ad molestias est architecto, quae aperiam sunt eaque veritatis aliquid fugiat maxime. Impedit?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it work just want to know how to make this picture big on mobile device... its showing very small on mobile device to to position absoulute behaviour

Comment: you can just change the value of the img in different breakpoints you can check that link i made an example for you https://jsfiddle.net/dpc8auts/

Answer (score 0):

Here what you need as per screenshot is to slice the laptop image with the pattern in png format and place it in a div and make it absolute relative to main banner section.

Hope this is helpful to you. kindly check the example snippet.

```css
.banner {
height: 500px;
position: relative;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background: #eee;
z-index: 1;
}

.content {
padding: 30px 0;
}

.ab {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Hello Dummy is here</h1>
  
  <div class="ab">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eY8X5d/Untitled_1.png">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h1>Hello Dummy is here</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. but it didnt show the exact look.

Comment: If you can download the zip http://www.djgt.co.uk/random/ and do it it will be great. badly need to complete this.

Comment: Extremely Sorry bro, i am in office and i cannot work on it currently. You just need to place image and make position absolute.